# Splines in R: Location of knots when only df is defined

Tags: r, spline

I have defined a logistic model for a complex survey with splines for the variable edadt defining the degrees of freedom, but not the position of the knots. After running the model:

```
    > log3<-svyglm(compo ~  bs(edadt,degree=1, df = 3), dclus, family = quasibinomial)
```

I would like to know where bs has located the knots. When I type:

> splineKnots(log3)

This is what I get:

```
    Error in UseMethod("splineKnots") : 
    no applicable method for 'splineKnots' applied to an object of class "c('svyglm', 'glm',      'lm')"
```

Any alternative to know the position of the knots?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `splineKnots` function doesn't work on many objects.  I think you'll have to write your own method for it:

```
library(splines)
splineKnots.default <- function(object) attr(object, "knots")
edadt <- rnorm(1000)
splineKnots(bs(edadt,degree=1, df = 3))
```

Notice that this works on `bs(edadt,degree=1, df = 3)`, not on `log3`.
If you really want it to work on `log3`, you'll have to figure out what class that object is, and find whether it has the result of `bs(edadt,degree=1, df = 3)` stored in it anywhere, or the formula so you can reconstruct it.

Comment: Thank you. I don´t need to inspect log3. Just with splineKnots(bs(edadt,degree=1, df = 3)) I get the position of the knots